# WebPacker not loading module (metisMenu)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpacker, metismenu

I'm facing an issue with loading the plugin [metisMenu](https://github.com/onokumus/metismenu) in Webpacker/Rails 6

I keep getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).metisMenu is not a function`

These are the contents from `application.js`:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import '../stylesheets/application'
import 'assets/images'

import 'bootstrap'

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

import 'metismenu'

import 'assets/javascripts/vendor.js'
import 'assets/javascripts/app.js'
import 'assets/stylesheets/icons.css'
import 'assets/stylesheets/app-creative.css'
```

config/webpack/environment.js:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

Comment: did you include jquery?

Comment: Yes, I did :`yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js metismenu` and put the config in `environment.js` accordingly. E.g: `$('H1').html('Change H1 text')` is working
`

Comment: The error means you have not included the metis menu JS file in the HTML page correctly. We can't help further than that as you've not included that code in the question

Comment: That' true, but I don't see where it all went wrong. I did a `yarn add metismenu` and put consequently `import 'metismenu'` in my `application.js`. If I check my `/node_modules` folder, it is present. Other JS libraries seems to be included fine.

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is that this code works before metisMenu is fully loaded. A solution cannot be produced without seeing your configuration.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I can get it to work when I load the library in from the `<head>` section by simply doing `<script src="https://unpkg.com/metismenu"></script>`. But loading it through Webpacker gives me the above error.